# Problems with Bake lights

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

How can i get better quality of the walls? When the lights set to realtime everything looks great, when i set it baked other object is not so bad but walls looks so ugly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show the same scene from the same vantage point, hard to compare apples to pears.

Comment: You have to learn bake settings first. Then try different settings in order to get better look. it is not simple, require time

Comment: I solved the problem by using Progressive Lightmapper!